# Find Segment of Video in another Video

Tags: video, similarity

we have the following problem: We have a pool of input videos (about 2-5 minutes per video) and a pool of output videos. Now we want to automatically find out which input video (or parts thereof), is used in an output video. Ideally, not only be recognized that an input video was used, but also how many seconds are used. The input video can also be edited (color , cut-outs , etc). One idea would be to create screenshots (every 10 seconds) from the Input video to search the output videos afterwards and analyze the similarity.

Is there a unix software tool? or someone has an idea ?

Comment: How did the output videos come into existence?  If some person made them, why wasn't the information of how they were made recorded?

Answer (score 0):

The usual technology to do what you are asking is called 'Fingerprinting'.

This essentially builds a fingerprint of frames or scenes in the original video and then searches others videos to see if it finds a match.

The complexity in this technology is both in the technique used to actually produce a fingerprint for a frame, and also in the ability to work even when the video is rescaled, resized, played within a border in the video etc.

There is a good overview in this academic paper:

- http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~farid/dfd/index.php/publications/show/400